# Javascript Not Picking Up var?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<input type="text" id="user" />
<button onclick="submit();" href="javascript:;">Submit</button>

<iframe src="http://google.com" id="openBox" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>

<script>
  function submit() {
      var getWebsite = document.getElementById('user');
      document.getElementById("openBox").src = getWebsite;
  }
</script>
```

I want the source to change dependent on what is inside the input box. The src ins't changing the iframes, instead i think its adding "getWebsite" to the source rather than the user's input.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
var getWebsite = document.getElementById('user').value;
```

You were setting the `getWebsite` variable to `<input type="text" id="user" />`, instead of the value of that input field.

Comment: He'll also have to change the `button` to `type="button"` to stop it submitting the page (and realise the `href` is doing nothing). **EDIT**: Infact, only if the `<button>` is inside a form, which it doesn't seem to be in the example.

Comment: @Matt: I see no reason for the button to be actually submitting the page at the moment. It only has the `Submit` label, and it's calling a function called `submit`... But since it's not actually in a form, as you said, it's not a problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add .value to get the input value not the element:

```
<script>
  function submit() {
      var getWebsite = document.getElementById('user').value;
      document.getElementById("openBox").src = getWebsite;
  }
</script>
```